# Making a Slash Command visible only to the owner in Nextcord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, nextcord

I am trying to make some slash commands only visible to the bot owner, like commands to load/unload my cogs, etc.

The following is my code:

```
@client.slash_command(name="load", description="Cog Loader",guild_ids=[937755377901133896])
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(interaction: Interaction, cog: str = nextcord.SlashOption(name="cogs", description="Name of the Cog.")):
    try:
        await client.load_extension(cog)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Loaded: {cog}")
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}")

@client.slash_command(name="unload", description="Cog Unloader",guild_ids=[937755377901133896])
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(interaction: Interaction, cog: str = nextcord.SlashOption(name="cogs", description="Name of the Cog.")):
    try:
        await client.unload_extension(cog)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Unloaded: {cog}")
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: No you can't do it. You only can specify your slash cmd to a the server you want in guilds_ids. You can use `if interaction.user == youruserid` to prevent others using this command but it still visible to everyone. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Guess i will have to make a private server for these specific commands , Thnx for the comment :)

Answer (score 3):

You could make it only accessible to admins by doing
(this is normal discord.py not nextcord.py, didn't see it was nextcord until after posting)

```
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not authorized to run this command.", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        #do your admin command here
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides making the command only accessible to admins you can also add `, ephemeral=True` at the end of your ctx.send to make it only appear to the user that sent it. such as.

```
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(interaction: Interaction, cog: str = nextcord.SlashOption(name="cogs", description="Name of the Cog.")):
    try:
        await client.load_extension(cog)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Loaded: {cog}", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}", ephemeral=True)

@client.slash_command(name="unload", description="Cog Unloader",guild_ids=[937755377901133896])
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(interaction: Interaction, cog: str = nextcord.SlashOption(name="cogs", description="Name of the Cog.")):
    try:
        await client.unload_extension(cog)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Unloaded: {cog}", ephemeral=True)
    except Exception as e:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Error: {e}", ephemeral=True)
```